# dbt pre hook deleting a table that was not built yet

Tags: sql, macros, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jinja2, dbt

This is my dbt config

```
{{
  config(
    materialized='incremental',
    incremental_strategy='append',
    pre_hook='DELETE FROM {{ this }} WHERE r_date <> CURRENT_DATE
  )
}}
```

This model is to be run on DBT.

I received an error upon dbt run command, and it was from pre_hook, as a standard SQL error, suggesting my prehook couldn't find `{{ this }}` model to delete data from.

Does a one time DDL is needed to create the skeleton of this model before this one can be run by dbt?

Comment: I posted an answer that will do what you're asking for. But just a side note - it seems like this should just be a `table` materialization.

Answer (score 3):

You can have the pre-hook optionally run depending on if you're doing a full refresh vs incremental job run.

```
{{
  config(
    materialized='incremental',
    incremental_strategy='append',
    pre_hook='{% if is_incremental() %} DELETE FROM {{ this }} WHERE r_date <> CURRENT_DATE {% endif %}'
  )
}}
```